# Access to the blocked websites on Ubuntu Mobile

Tags: ubuntu-touch, vpn

I want to install **Ubuntu Touch** on Samsung Note4.

As you may know, most of social networks (*Facebook, Twitter, YouTube, Telegram,* etc.) are **blocked** in Iran by the government.
So, we have to use **Free VPN Apps** (such as *Turbo VPN, Psiphone, TunnelBear*) to access the social networks on Android.

**How can I use blocked apps or websites on Ubuntu Mobile?**

The url of VPNs are blocked in Iran by the government. We install them from Google play store

Answer (score 1):

You can use openconnect to connect to VPN.

Open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo openconnect url.of.vpn.provider
```

Then enter your username and password.
You need to keep the terminal open as long as you need to remain connected.

Comment: The url of VPNs are blocked in Iran by the government. We install them from Google play store